# custom print statement for python function objects

Tags: python, functional-programming

I know that if I write a class, I can definite a custom print function as below.

```
>>> class F:
...     def __str__(self):
...             return 'This describes the data of F.'
... 
>>> f = F()
>>> print f
This describes the data of F.
```

But, what if I want to do the same for a function object? For example,

```
>>> def f():
...     pass
... 
>>> g = f
>>> print g
<function f at 0x7f738d6da5f0>
```

Instead of '<function f at 0x7f738d6da5f0>', I'd like to somehow specify what was printed. The motivation for doing this is that I'm going to store a bunch of function objects in a list, and I'd like to iterate over the list and print human-readable descriptions of the types of functions without adding additional complexity, e.g., tuples of function objects and strings.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

**Edit:** I changed my example to reflect what I was trying to convey, unfortunately I typed 'f()' when I meant 'f'. I am interested in a custom label for the function object, not customizing the return (which it is obvious how to do). Sorry for any confusion this has caused.

Comment: `g` is the return value of `f`. Are you storing _functions_ in the list, or their _return values_?

Comment: Do you mean the function object f? or the return value from f()? calling f() which passes actually returns None. Your example is not printing f, it is printing f().

Comment: Hmmm... weirdly enough, changing the `__repr__` and `__str__` special methods of a function object seems to do nothing. It's surprising that Python doesn't allow these to be overridden while not also raising an error which it does, for example, if you try to override the `__repr__` method of a `list` object.

Comment: @Chinmay Kanchi: See my answer. These are method-wrappers.

Comment: @pyfunc: Yes, but so is the `__repr__` method of a `list` object. And attempting to override that raises an error. Whereas overriding the `__repr__` method of a function object seemingly replaces the method, but has no effect on `repr()` or `str()` calls. Bug or at least an inconsistency, methinks.

Comment: @Chinmay Kanchi: Yes very true. These are python internals and read only. If you create your own class, then you can provide __str__ and __repr__.

Comment: @pyfunc: Yes, but a Python function object should also have read-only attributes, as it is effectively a built-in. You either allow the change and change the result of `repr()` and/or `str()` calls, or you don't and raise an `AttributeError`. Doesn't make sense to allow ineffectual changes. If I can get someone to test that this is true on Python 2.7, I might report it as a bug...

Comment: @Chinmay: overriding those methods won't help because it uses the object's type's `__repr__` rather than the object's `__repr__`. So it uses `<type 'function'>`'s `__repr__`, not `somefunc`'s `__repr__`

Comment: `__str__` is not a "custom print fuction". It's the function that is called when you convert something to a string.

The correct answer to your question is: "Use docstrings".

Comment: And in what way is tuples of fucntions and string "adding additional complexity" compared to other solutions? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few errors:

```
>>> def f():
...     pass
... 
>>> g = f()     <---- g is the return value of running f
>>> print g
None
```

in the first case, when you call print, you are calling a string representation of f

```
>>> f = F()
>>> print f    <----- f is an instance of class F and 
               <----- print f tries to provide a suitable string representation
               <----- by calling f.__str__
```

**You should use doc strings for your motives**

```
>>> def f():
...     " some doc"
...     pass
... 
>>> 
>>> f.__doc__
' some doc'
>>>
```

What you are trying to do is override the method wrapper `__str__`.

```
>>> def f():
...     "some documentation .."
...     pass
... 
>>> 
>>> f.__str__
<method-wrapper '__str__' of function object at 0x100430140>
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew about this before but it was not obvious (to me) that all I needed to do was call "print g.__doc__".

Answer (score 9):

Others have suggested doc strings, but a doc string should probably be more descriptive of what the function does.  If you want a short attribute describing the function, one of the options below may be what you are looking for:

### Option 1

Are you saying you want to change the default description of a function object?

```
>>> def f1(): pass
...
>>> def f2(): pass
...
>>> L = [f1,f2]
>>> print L
[<function f1 at 0x00AA72F0>, <function f2 at 0x00AA73B0>]
```

If you want to customize the description of the functions in the list above, use a [decorator](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-decorator).  The decorator below wraps each function decorated into an object that acts like the original function, but has a custom representation:

```
def doc(s):
    class __doc(object):
        def __init__(self,f):
            self.func = f
            self.desc = s
        def __call__(self,*args,**kwargs):
            return self.func(*args,**kwargs)
        def __repr__(self):
            return '<function {0} "{1}">'.format(self.func.func_name,self.desc)
    return __doc

@doc('a+b')
def sum(a,b):
    return a + b

@doc('a-b')
def diff(a,b):
    return a - b

L = [sum,diff]
print L
for f in L:
    print f(5,3)
```

#### Output

```
[<function sum "a+b">, <function diff "a-b">]
8
2
```

### Option 2

Alternatively, you can store attributes in your functions and display them as needed:

```
def sum(a,b):
    return a + b
sum.desc = 'a+b'

def diff(a,b):
    return a-b
diff.desc = 'a-b'

L = [sum,diff]
for f in L:
    print f.desc,f(8,3)
```

#### Output

```
a+b 11
a-b 5
```

### Option 3

You can do option 2 with a decorator also:

```
def doc(s):
    def __doc(f):
        f.desc = s
        return f
    return __doc

@doc('a+b')
def sum2(a,b):
    return a + b

@doc('a-b')
def diff2(a,b):
    return a - b

L = [sum2,diff2]
for f in L:
    print f.desc,f(8,3)
```

#### Output

```
a+b 11
a-b 5
```

Comment: Although all this works, it's just a different way of adding documentation to a function after the creation of it. If he wanted to add documentation when the function was added to the list, he could just make the list contains tuples of functions and reasons why it was in the list.

Comment: @Lennart: True, but he specifically said he didn't want "tuples of function objects and strings."

Comment: Thank you. These are both viable approaches, but I think I am looking for something much simpler (doc strings). This is obviously a more powerful approach if more requirements need to be met.

Answer (score 2):

You cant change what happens when you print a function, but you can make a class behave like a function:

```
class f(object):
    def __str__(self):
        return "I'm a function!"

    def __call__(self):
        print "who called?"


print f # I'm a function!
f() # who called?
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions return values. The value assigned to `g` variable is going to be printed. If you want to print something, just make sure the function `f`, returns a string.

```
>>> def f():
...     return "Print me"
... 
>>> g = f()
>>> print g
Print me
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> g = f # no ()! That *calls* the function.
>>> print g
<function f at 0x########>
```